# Apply locks in stored procedure for a block with insert and select clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, amazon-aurora

I am working on a project to migrate from MSSQL to MYSQL Inno DB version 5.7.11(AWS Aurora).

For a specific table, I want to insert a certain limit of records on a daily basis for each category. This count is configurable. In SQL Server I used `sp_getapplock` for my condition check before inserting, and to release the lock (commit transaction) after insert was completed.

Can some one help me on how to achieve this using MySQL?

Sample Code in MSSQL:

```
BEGIN
EXEC @return_code = sp_getapplock 
@Resource = @resource_key, 
@LockMode = 'Exclusive',                  
@LockOwner = 'Transaction'; 

select @total_to_be_allocated_daily=count(1) from table11 where category=@inputcategory

select @total_already_inserted_today = count(1) from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id and t1.category=@inputcategory 

set @pending_to_be_allocated=@total_to_be_allocated_daily-@total_already_inserted_today

if(@pending_to_be_allocated>0)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO table1 (col1,co2,col3,col4)
 select top @pending_to_be_allocated col1,col2,col3,col4
 from @input_udt i
 left join table1 t1 on i.col3=t1.col3
 left join table2 t2 on t2.col4=t1.col4
 where t2.col4 is null

EXEC @return_code = sp_releaseapplock 
                     @Resource = @resource_key;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

This procedure allows concurrent execution (there are other operations also done in the procedure which is not captured in the sample code). I need sequential execution for a specific block of code which is captured in the above sample.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Shadow Not convinced that's massively helpful for OP. The solution here is probably more likely to be: do the whole thing in a single query, which is eminently possible

Comment: You probably want to combine the whole thing into one query, but since the `limit` has to be a constant or variable then you would need to use `row_number` instead

Comment: @Charlieface I disagree as the OP wants to make sure that a piece of code is executed sequentially. get_lock() achieves precisely that. Combining the above logic into a single query may or may not achieve that.

Comment: @Shadow Firstly, I think it will achieve that. Secondly, arguably the current code is badly flawed anyway, as it doesn't prevent any changes to the tables in between statements

Comment: @Charlieface the OP has to make sure that all relevant code uses the same locking code. That's not a change from his existing code. We simply do not know enough. get_locks() is a direct translation of the OP's current logic, therefore it is completely valid answer.

Comment: @Charlieface Can you help me understand what is flawed in the query? In MSSQL, per my knowledge as soon as sp_applock is executed lock is applied on the whole transaction, And any concurrent requests automatically waits in the queue. No concurrent execution on a particular block/transaction is allowed. So even in between statements, the lock still holds valid. Now with GetLock() in MySQL It allows me to acquire lock on a particular key, if there are multiple calls at the same time, should I add a polling mechanism to check if the lock is released?

Comment: Correct, but if there is any other code that accesses `table1` and `table2` without using that lock then it is not protected. Whereas a single query would use standard row and page locking. Incidentally `left join table2 t2 on t2.col4=t1.col4 where t2.col4 is null` should probably be rewritten `where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where  t2.col4 = t1.col4)`

Comment: @Charlieface It is intentionally written this way, table1 and table2 allow inserts from other stored procedures in multiple other flows, only a specific flow in one specific procedure has the locking mechanism. The joins are that are mentioned here are for representational purpose, they are actually service my specific purpose on checking for some redundancy and to check few categories are active.

Comment: I wasn't very sure on how to use GetLock() to replace sp_applock. Getlock() doesnt have a auto queueing mechanism in case of concurrent requests. Could you help with a sample implementation? Is polling the only option or is there something else that is available in MYSQL?